# #1054 - Unknown column 'ï»¿NULL' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export, mysql-workbench

I exported a table with Workbench but cannot import it to phpmyadmin!

This is the script:

```
    -- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 03/28/15 13:10:20
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema khayyamk_khayyam
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `khayyamk_khayyam` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `khayyamk_khayyam` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUserCreated` INT NULL,
  `DateAdded` DATETIME NULL,
  `DateModified` DATETIME NULL,
  `Deleted` TINYINT NULL,
  `Title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `khayyamk_khayyam`;
INSERT INTO `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle` (`id`, `idUserCreated`, `DateAdded`, `DateModified`, `Deleted`, `Title`) VALUES (﻿NULL, NULL, 'NULL', 'NULL', 0, 'Visitor');
COMMIT;
```

And this is the error:

```
    INSERT INTO `khayyamk_khayyam`.`JobTitle` (`id`, `idUserCreated`, `DateAdded`, `DateModified`, `Deleted`, `Title`) VALUES (﻿NULL, NULL, 'NULL', 'NULL', 0, 'ويزيتور');

#1054 - Unknown column 'ï»¿NULL' in 'field list'
```

After some research I found a red dot before first NULL.See this image:
[image: Weird red dot in phpmyadmin]

But there is nothing shown in Notepad++.

Is this a bug? How can I get rid of it in next export?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have some hidden character, try to write the query in a simple text file.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. But how can I prevent this on next export?